# Web service restful + projeto java comum

Tags: java, web-service, restful

Estou com o seguinte problema, possuo um web service de teste criado em um projeto(I) separado no eclipse e um outro projeto de java(II)(Drools). Como faço para os dois se comunicarem estando em diferentes projetos?

Já tentei pelo ***Build Path -> Project -> add***
,mas quando tento chamar qualquer método do projeto(II) ele aparece esse erro:

```
ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
GRAVE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sample/DroolsTest
```

Alguém saberia como resolver?

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sample/DroolsTest` sugere que algum JAR (provavelmente do Drools) com esta classe está faltando na sua aplicação. Entretanto, não acho que a sua aplicação devesse precisar dessa classe. Pode postar todo o seu stacktrace e a lista de JARs que está utilizando? E também, qual é o tipo do seu servidor JavaEE?

Comment: Utilizando o maven, você poderia adicionar o seu projeto como dependência. Fora isso, gere um jar do seu projeto que contém a classe DroolsTest e adicione as suas libs e faça o registro desse jar no classpath do seu projeto principal.